# return subarray of object based on object key in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Given this data structure:

```
let assets = [{
  "photos": [{
    "id": 1,
    "label": "bad-syn.jpg",
    "size": 38284
  }]
}, {
  "documents": [{
    "id": 109
  }]
}]
```

]

How can I retrieve the subarray based on the `photos` key? There can be other keys.

My function just returns the entire structure:

```
findAssets: function (key) {
  return this.assets.find((asset) => {
    return asset[key]
  })
}
```

Comment: Don't you want map, not find? The find callback's return value is only used for truthiness.

Comment: Your current function looks like it's almost there, you have the object, now access the value

Comment: Just a comment about the design of this data structure. Is the outer-object with the "photos" key going to be the only object in the outer-array?

Comment: *"There can be many other kinds of key"*. This is not clear. Is there going to be only one object in `assets` with `photos` as key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return the `photos` sub `array` or in other words only the value of the given `key`, you just want to access the `key` value from the `.find()` result using `[key]`:

```
findAssets =  function(key){
  return assets.find((asset) => {
    return asset[key]
  })[key]
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
let assets = [{
  "photos": [{
    "id": 1,
    "label": "bad-syn.jpg",
    "size": 38284
  }]
}]

findAssets =  function(key){
  return assets.find((asset) => {
    return asset[key]
  })[key]
}

console.log(findAssets("photos"));
```

**Note:**

This assumes the given `key`exists in your `assets` objects, otherwise it can throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `.map()` and because `photos` is an array as well you need to map twice.

```js
let assets = [{
  "photos": [{
    "id": 1,
    "label": "bad-syn.jpg",
    "size": 38284
  }]
}]

function byKey(k) {
  return assets.map(a => a.photos.map(p => p[k]));
}

console.log(byKey('label'));
```